# Writing different years in a data frame list to separate textfiles using R

Tags: r

I've created a large list of elements separated by year like so:

```
1961: 'data.frame': 365 obs of 4 variables:
..$ Year: int [1:365]
..$ Rainfall: int [1:365]
..$ PET: int [1:365]
..$ MeanT: int [1:365]
1962: 'data.frame': 365 obs of 4 variables:
..$ Year: int [1:365]
..$ Rainfall: int [1:365]
..$ PET: int [1:365]
..$ MeanT: int [1:365]
```

...all the way up to 2007. I want to create separate text files for each year to be used in another program, containing the four columns of data without the column headers.

It would be simple to do this in excel but I have a lot of data to process and would like to be able to use R to automate the process and save a good deal of time.

Comment: You can use `lapply` i.e. `lapply(names(lst), function(x) write.csv(x, file=paste0('file', x,'.csv'), quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE))`

Comment: try: `lapply(mylist, function(x) write.table(x, file= myfilename, quote=FALSE, col.names=FALSE))`

Comment: @akrun thanks for your help - this writes all the files but they are not populated by the data, just by the year. Each textfile just contains the corresponding year

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand your comment.  If there are NULL list elements, you need to subset it. `lst1 <- lst[!sapply(lst, is.null)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having chatted with Pad, on reddit, we found a solution, it is based on akrun's and Pierre's comments from above:

```
lapply(names(lst),function(x) write.table(cbind(c(1:dim(lst[[x]])[1]), lst[[x]][-1]), file = paste0('',x,'.txt'), quote = F, row.names = F, col.names = F, sep = ","))
```

In addition to writing the file, the code also removes the first column, substituting it with the numbers from 1-365 (or 1 to the number of rows in the provided data.frame).

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's R heresy, but even though it may run slower, a for loop will make it easy to get the file name from the list item name:

```
for(i in 1:length(mylist)){
  filename <- paste0(names(mylist)[i],".csv")
  write.table(mylist[[i]], file=filename, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep=",")
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot this works! there's still a problem with the output though, I want each textfile to have the numbers 1-365 at the start of each line, but this only works for the first year, after that it's 366-730 and so on.

It's also printing the year for each textfile, which I don't want. I only want the day from 1-365, I'll play around with it and see if I can fix it! Thanks for the help.